# Problem creating multiple event listeners and removing them upon completion

Tags: c#

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the following functionality I am trying to implement.

I have what I call a repairManager for a space ship. This keeps track of a variable (int repairBots ) that can be used to send repairBots to repair broken systems on the ship. This is used to limit how many bots can be used (currently 3)
Throughout my ship I have systems using a repair script that can repair the object they are attached to when the repairManager sends a bot over.

**REPAIR MANAGER**

```
 public void SendRepairBot(MyHealthRecharger systemToRepair)
{
    if (availableRepairBots > 0) // Prevents sending more repair bots than owned
    {
        systemToRepair.onFinishedRepairing.AddListener((bots) => { SetRepairBotAmount(bots); });

        systemToRepair.RepairBotsAmount += 1;
        availableRepairBots -= 1;
    }
}
```

I have a script that can recall a bot one at a time (If needed for deployment elsewhere)

```
public void RecallRepairBot(MyHealthRecharger systemToRepair)
{
    systemToRepair.onFinishedRepairing.RemoveListener((bots) => { SetRepairBotAmount(bots); });

    if (availableRepairBots < maxRepairBots && systemToRepair.RepairBotsAmount > 0) // Prevents recalling more repair bots than sent
    {
        systemToRepair.RepairBotsAmount -= 1;
        availableRepairBots += 1;
    }
}
```

**REPAIR SCRIPT SITTING ON VARIOUS OBJECTS UPDATE FUNCTION**

```
private void Update()
{
   if (repairBotsAmount > 0)
            Recharge(repairBotsAmount);
}
```

On my repair script I created an event for when the repair bot finishes repairing the object entirely. This event takes an INT. The int is the amount of repair bots this repair script has received (so it can return them when completed)

```
public class OnFinishedRepairingEventHandler : UnityEvent<int> { }
...
...
public OnFinishedRepairingEventHandler onFinishedRepairing;
```

**The function on the RepairScript that invokes the event**

```
public virtual void Recharge(int bots )
{
  *do some healing*
   if (currentHealth == maxhealth)
   {
       onFinishedRepairing.Invoke(bots);
       repairBotsAmount = 0; 
   }
```

Everything works pretty smoothly until I get to adding listeners to the event.

I can send out up to 3 bots.
For this example lets say to the same system needing repairs (for quicker completion time)

I send out 1 Bot -> RepairManager reads 2 remaining -> upon completion RepairManager reads 3. Ok so far so good.

I send out 1 Bot, then recall it, then send it out again -> RepairManager reads 2 remaining -> upon completion RepairManager reads 4. Uh oh.

I send out 1 Bot, then recall it and send it out 2 more times -> RepairManager reads 2 remaining -> upon completion RepairManager reads 5. It gets weirder.

I send out 2 Bots -> RepairManager reads 1 remaining -> upon completion RepairManager reads 5.

I send out 2 Bots -> RepairManager reads 1 remaining -> I recall 1 before completion -> RepairManager reads 2 remaining -> upon final bot completion RepairManager reads 4.

I know I missed something in my code I just can't quite nail it down. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: After a bunch more testing I think my problem is reusing the same listener.
Sending out 3 bots returns 9 to me when they're done because the last one added the listener with three bots in use so all three listeners called back 3 bots when invoked.

I need to figure out how to make one and only one listener